# How to connect Microsoft SQL server in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sql-server

Is there any way to connect SQL Server in iPhone to retrieve data? If yes, then please send me any link or any idea to develop this functionality...

Answer (score 4):

To talk to SQL Server natively, you'll need an Objective-C library which implements [TDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream) protocol. There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528634/how-to-access-sql-server-from-cocoa-mac-os-x) here on SO, but it's OSX related.

What you can do is to use [Native XML Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345123%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 onwards and use these from you iPhone app.

Comment: Can i integrate SQL Server in ios??

Comment: Please tell me any way to connect SQL Server in iOS?