# Connect to MSSQL DB from iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, sql-server

I know that directly connection  DB is not good idea, but I need it(MS SQL). So the question is: is there some library, preferable written on Objective-C/C and compiled to a static lib, which give desired result?

I know about FreeTDS, but I don't know how to build it. Is there xcode project with it, or how can I make it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use the way answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993516/how-to-connect-microsoft-sql-server-in-iphone

Comment: Yes, the DB stored on remote server.